# Jenkins Pipeline and docker inspect

Tags: batch-file, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline which uses docker-container. I want to check if the docker container is there and if it is not there I want to start it.
I use a docker-compose to start the container. 
My code

```
            script{

                if ((NOT "bat 'docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} compiler_code'")){
                    echo "Container is not running; Starting it"
                    bat 'start cmd.exe /k "docker-compose up compiler"'
                }
            }
```

This is not working
[image]

Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use docker-compose up --no-recreate.

You need to specify the flag:
    --no-recreate              If containers already exist, don't recreate
                               them.

Comment: so you mean i can just use docker-compose up  --no-recreate and I don't need to know if the Container is already running?

Comment: Yes, as docker-compose up will start the container unless they are already running. You can have detailed look here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/